# Laravel PHP Unit Testing

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.4, laravel-testing

I am just testing my laravel app with phpunit 
When i run `vendor/bin/phpunit` i am getting error like below `Error: Call to undefined method ExampleTest::assertStatus()`

Below is the code i was trying to execute

```
$response = $this->json('POST', '/users', ['customer_name' => 'Ratke-Harris']);

        $response
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertExactJson([
                'created' => true,
            ]);
```

As per the laravel docs , even there they have mentioned the same example. I don't understand why it is throwing  error.

Any ideas ? Please.

Answer (score 4):

Change `->assertStatus(200)` to `->assertResponseStatus(200)`

Comment: this is the right answer. There appears to be an error in their documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests

Answer (score 0):

Just change `use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` with `use Tests\TestCase` in the top of your test class:))